# Ruby on Rails: Processing CSS Lint and JS Lint "realtime" with uploaded files

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, jslint

Our application allows users to upload javascript, CSS, and HTML files.  We need a way to validate these files against CSS and JS lint, as well as record any errors associated with them (file name, line, etc).  This needs to be done "realtime," or at the least passed off to a delayed job process to work in the background.  The requirements won't allow us to hook into a third-party online service (like the online w3c validator).

I've found jshint_on_rails and jslint_on_rails, which seems like they could work.  They are reliant on rake tasks, however, and I'm not sure how I would get their output into a database.  I have thus far not found anything similar for css lint.  Are there packages like this out there that I could hook into?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was installing the Node.js versions of JSHint and CSSLint, and then calling them through Rails and parsing the output, like so:

```
  def validate_js(filepath)
    capture_error = false
    filename = get_filename(filepath)
    file_regex = Regexp.new(filepath)
    lint_config = "--config #{Rails.root}/test/validators/jshint.json"
    lint_reporter = "--reporter #{Rails.root}/test/validators/jshint-reporter.js"

    IO.popen("jshint #{filepath} #{lint_config} #{lint_reporter}") do |pipe|

      pipe.each do |line|
        if line =~ file_regex
          # Error detected
          error_msg = line.split("#{filepath}: ").last.strip
          @js_error = @instance.parse_warnings.new(:filename => filename, :error_type => 'javascript', 
                                                        :error_message => error_msg)
          capture_error = true
        elsif capture_error 
          # The actual line the error is on
          @js_error.error_content = line
          @js_error.save!

          capture_error = false
          @js_error = nil # Empty the variable so it isn't hanging around after the last error
        end
      end
    end
  end



def validate_css(filepath)
    filename = get_filename(filepath)
    dir = File.expand_path(File.dirname(filepath)) # Where we want to dump the results.xml file

    system("csslint --format=lint-xml > #{dir}/#{filename}-results.xml #{filepath}") # Call CSSLint

    output = LibXML::XML::Parser.file("#{dir}/#{filename}-results.xml")
    doc = output.parse # Iterate over the errors
    doc.find('//issue').each do |issue|
      error_msg = "line #{issue['line']}, col #{issue['char']}, #{issue['reason']}"
      error_content = issue['evidence']
      @instance.parse_warnings.create!(:filename => filename, :error_type => 'css', :error_message => error_msg,
                                            :error_content => error_content)
    end
    FileUtils.rm("#{dir}/#{filename}-results.xml") # No need to keep the xml file around
  end
```